# Printing a list in a specific order

Tags: sorting, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have a program that generates 4 numbers and appends it to a list. The items of each list are lists themselves, looking something like:

```
[['+', 1, 1, 9, 9], ['+', 2, 1, 4, 4]]
[['+', 2, 1, 10, 10], ['+', 3, 1, 5, 5]]
[['+', 1, 1, 6, 6], ['+', 3, 1, 11, 11]]
[['-', 1, 1, 9, 9], ['-', 2, 1, 4, 4]]
```

I am trying to print them so that the last digits are in a descending order (if its the same last digit, then it uses the third number in descending order).

My code so far is:

```
for i in self.result:
        sorted(self.result, key=itemgetter(4), reverse = True)
        print("{}{:d} {:>5d}..{:>5d} {:>5d}\n" .format(i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4]))
```

The problem is, that doesn't seem to print them in an ordered fashion at all, so I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: You seem to have **four** lists at the top? Was that your intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted()` returns a new list, which you aren't capturing. You want either `slist = sorted(...)` or `oldlist.sort(...)`. The latter case sorts in place.

To sort as you want, use this:

```
thelist.sort(key=lambda x:list(reversed(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks! So that allows me to set up one rule for sorting (for me using the 4th digit). How can I add another rule that if there is 2 with the same 4th digit, the one with the bigger 3rd digit comes first?

Comment: @lamazibiji: It already does that. It sorts by the entire inner list, but with its items reversed.